# Using AcoustID API in Android app

Tags: android, api, musicbrainz

I want to make an Android app that uses `AcoustID` API. From my understanding that is a c++ API and i should use Android NDK for this. The curious thing is that i found a sample of this API written in Java and i don't know if this is actually AcoustID API or some adaptation.

Also if using AcoustID means that i have to use NDK i would like to know if there is a Java alternative for it. I couldn't find satisfying results.

This is the Java sample i've found:

```
package net.filebot.web;

import static java.util.Collections.*;
import static net.filebot.util.FileUtilities.*;
import static net.filebot.web.WebRequest.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.Icon;

import net.filebot.Cache;
import net.filebot.ResourceManager;

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class AcoustIDClient implements MusicIdentificationService {

    private static final FloodLimit REQUEST_LIMIT = new FloodLimit(3, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    private String apikey;

    public AcoustIDClient(String apikey) {
        this.apikey = apikey;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "AcoustID";
    }

    @Override
    public Icon getIcon() {
        return ResourceManager.getIcon("search.acoustid");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<File, AudioTrack> lookup(Iterable<File> files) throws Exception {
        Map<File, AudioTrack> results = new LinkedHashMap<File, AudioTrack>();

        for (Map<String, String> fp : fpcalc(files)) {
            results.put(new File(fp.get("FILE")), parse(lookup(fp.get("DURATION"), fp.get("FINGERPRINT"))));
        }
        return results;
    }

    public String lookup(File file) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> fp = fpcalc(singleton(file)).get(0);
        return lookup(fp.get("DURATION"), fp.get("FINGERPRINT"));
    }

    public String lookup(String duration, String fingerprint) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException {
        // http://api.acoustid.org/v2/lookup?client=8XaBELgH&meta=recordings+releasegroups+compress&duration=641&fingerprint=AQABz0qUkZK4oOfhL-CPc4e5C_wW2H2QH9uDL4cvoT8UNQ-eHtsE8cceeFJx-LiiHT-aPzhxoc-Opj_eI5d2hOFyMJRzfDk-QSsu7fBxqZDMHcfxPfDIoPWxv9C1o3yg44d_3Df2GJaUQeeR-cb2HfaPNsdxHj2PJnpwPMN3aPcEMzd-_MeB_Ej4D_CLP8ghHjkJv_jh_UDuQ8xnILwunPg6hF2R8HgzvLhxHVYP_ziJX0eKPnIE1UePMByDJyg7wz_6yELsB8n4oDmDa0Gv40hf6D3CE3_wH6HFaxCPUD9-hNeF5MfWEP3SCGym4-SxnXiGs0mRjEXD6fgl4LmKWrSChzzC33ge9PB3otyJMk-IVC6R8MTNwD9qKQ_CC8kPv4THzEGZS8GPI3x0iGVUxC1hRSizC5VzoamYDi-uR7iKPhGSI82PkiWeB_eHijvsaIWfBCWH5AjjCfVxZ1TQ3CvCTclGnEMfHbnZFA8pjD6KXwd__Cn-Y8e_I9cq6CR-4S9KLXqQcsxxoWh3eMxiHI6TIzyPv0M43YHz4yte-Cv-4D16Hv9F9C9SPUdyGtZRHV-OHEeeGD--BKcjVLOK_NCDXMfx44dzHEiOZ0Z44Rf6DH5R3uiPj4d_PKolJNyRJzyu4_CTD2WOvzjKH9GPb4cUP1Av9EuQd8fGCFee4JlRHi18xQh96NLxkCgfWFKOH6WGeoe4I3za4c5hTscTPEZTES1x8kE-9MQPjT8a8gh5fPgQZtqCFj9MDvp6fDx6NCd07bjx7MLR9AhtnFnQ70GjOcV0opmm4zpY3SOa7HiwdTtyHa6NC4e-HN-OfC5-OP_gLe2QDxfUCz_0w9l65HiPAz9-IaGOUA7-4MZ5CWFOlIfe4yUa6AiZGxf6w0fFxsjTOdC6Itbh4mGD63iPH9-RFy909XAMj7mC5_BvlDyO6kGTZKJxHUd4NDwuZUffw_5RMsde5CWkJAgXnDReNEaP6DTOQ65yaD88HoeX8fge-DSeHo9Qa8cTHc80I-_RoHxx_UHeBxrJw62Q34Kd7MEfpCcu6BLeB1ePw6OO4sOF_sHhmB504WWDZiEu8sKPpkcfCT9xfej0o0lr4T5yNJeOvjmu40w-TDmqHXmYgfFhFy_M7tD1o0cO_B2ms2j-ACEEQgQgAIwzTgAGmBIKIImNQAABwgQATAlhDGCCEIGIIM4BaBgwQBogEBIOESEIA8ARI5xAhxEFmAGAMCKAURKQQpQzRAAkCCBQEAKkQYIYIQQxCixCDADCABMAE0gpJIgyxhEDiCKCCIGAEIgJIQByAhFgGACCACMRQEyBAoxQiHiCBCFOECQFAIgAABR2QAgFjCDMA0AUMIoAIMChQghChASGEGeYEAIAIhgBSErnJPPEGWYAMgw05AhiiGHiBBBGGSCQcQgwRYJwhDDhgCSCSSEIQYwILoyAjAIigBFEUQK8gAYAQ5BCAAjkjCCAEEMZAUQAZQCjCCkpCgFMCCiIcVIAZZgilAQAiSHQECOcQAQIc4QClAHAjDDGkAGAMUoBgyhihgEChFCAAWEIEYwIJYwViAAlHCBIGEIEAEIQAoBwwgwiEBAEEEOoEwBY4wRwxAhBgAcKAESIQAwwIowRFhoBhAE
        URL url = new URL("http://api.acoustid.org/v2/lookup?client=" + apikey + "&meta=recordings+releasegroups+releases+tracks+compress&duration=" + duration + "&fingerprint=" + fingerprint);

        Cache cache = Cache.getCache("web-datasource");
        String response = cache.get(url, String.class);
        if (response != null) {
            return response;
        }

        // respect rate limit
        REQUEST_LIMIT.acquirePermit();
        response = readAll(getReader(url.openConnection()));
        cache.put(url, response);

        return response;
    }

    public AudioTrack parse(String json) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException {
        Map<?, ?> data = (Map<?, ?>) new JSONParser().parse(json);

        if (!data.get("status").equals("ok")) {
            throw new IOException("acoustid responded with error: " + data.get("status"));
        }
        try {
            for (Object result : (List<?>) data.get("results")) {
                try {
                    Map<?, ?> recording = (Map<?, ?>) ((List<?>) ((Map<?, ?>) result).get("recordings")).get(0);

                    String artist = (String) ((Map<?, ?>) ((List<?>) recording.get("artists")).get(0)).get("name");
                    String title = (String) recording.get("title");

                    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(artist, title, null);
                    try {
                        Map<?, ?> releaseGroup = (Map<?, ?>) ((List<?>) recording.get("releasegroups")).get(0);
                        List<?> releases = (List<?>) releaseGroup.get("releases");

                        for (Object it : releases) {
                            try {
                                AudioTrack thisRelease = new AudioTrack(artist, title, null);
                                Map<?, ?> release = (Map<?, ?>) it;
                                Map<?, ?> date = (Map<?, ?>) release.get("date");
                                try {
                                    thisRelease.albumReleaseDate = new SimpleDate(Integer.parseInt(date.get("year").toString()), Integer.parseInt(date.get("month").toString()), Integer.parseInt(date.get("day").toString()));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // ignore
                                }

                                if (thisRelease.albumReleaseDate == null || thisRelease.albumReleaseDate.getTimeStamp() >= (audioTrack.albumReleaseDate == null ? Long.MAX_VALUE : audioTrack.albumReleaseDate.getTimeStamp())) {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                Map<?, ?> medium = (Map<?, ?>) ((List<?>) release.get("mediums")).get(0);
                                thisRelease.mediumIndex = new Integer(medium.get("position").toString());
                                thisRelease.mediumCount = new Integer(release.get("medium_count").toString());

                                Map<?, ?> track = (Map<?, ?>) ((List<?>) medium.get("tracks")).get(0);
                                thisRelease.trackIndex = new Integer(track.get("position").toString());
                                thisRelease.trackCount = new Integer(medium.get("track_count").toString());

                                try {
                                    thisRelease.album = release.get("title").toString();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    thisRelease.album = (String) releaseGroup.get("title");
                                }
                                try {
                                    thisRelease.albumArtist = (String) ((Map<?, ?>) ((List<?>) releaseGroup.get("artists")).get(0)).get("name");
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    thisRelease.albumArtist = null;
                                }
                                thisRelease.trackTitle = (String) track.get("title");

                                if (!"Various Artists".equalsIgnoreCase(thisRelease.albumArtist) && (thisRelease.album == null || !thisRelease.album.contains("Greatest Hits"))) {
                                    audioTrack = thisRelease;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // allow album to be null
                    }
                    return audioTrack;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getChromaprintCommand() {
        // use fpcalc executable path as specified by the cmdline or default to "fpcalc" and let the shell figure it out
        return System.getProperty("net.filebot.AcoustID.fpcalc", "fpcalc");
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> fpcalc(Iterable<File> files) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add(getChromaprintCommand());
        for (File f : files) {
            command.add(f.toString());
        }

        Process process = null;
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            try {
                processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Logger.getLogger(AcoustIDClient.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Unable to inherit IO: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            process = processBuilder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to exec fpcalc: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        LinkedList<Map<String, String>> results = new LinkedList<Map<String, String>>();

        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] value = scanner.nextLine().split("=", 2);
                if (value.length != 2)
                    continue;

                if (results.isEmpty() || results.getLast().containsKey(value[0])) {
                    results.addLast(new HashMap<String, String>(3));
                }
                results.getLast().put(value[0], value[1]);
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }

        if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to exec fpcalc: Exit code " + process.exitValue());
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I've found the source of the sample :
[Link to sample](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=h3_5XlkS_5m4gDpCH8Q2WUgygRg&cid=zOoT9U5sG98&s=&fp=2012&mp&projSelected=true#L0)
But i can't figure what is is or how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you even bothered to read the code? It obviously doesn't use any C++ library... as you can clearly see by the usage of Process it uses a Sub-Process to call fpcalc and as you can see by Process.getInputStream() it'll read from the standard output of said Sub-Process.

Comment: I read the code but i never thought that it uses a c++ library. I just didn't understand much of it, hence my 'call to help' here.